# PHP PDO finding found rows of a UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small problem that I need help solving.
Its more a lack in my MySQL knowledge then a problem really...

I have a table of employes something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employes (CoNo int, EmplCode int, Name varchar(250), Dep varchar(4))
```

It contains some data as such:

```
3 123 'John Jackson' 'INFO'
3 124 'Simon Says'   'SELL'
...
```

I am trying to update Simons row using PHP PDO (something like):

```
$sql = "UPDATE employes SET CoNo = 3, Name = 'Simon Says', Dep = 'SELL' WHERE EmplCode = 124";
$stmt = $PDOObject->prepare($sql);
$status = $stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

Now lets say everything is connecting and everything is working.
If you paid attention during your MySQL classes you will soon see that this will echo 0 rows affected.

Which apparently is a normal behavior for MySQL because the UPDATE didn't change anything to the actual data in the table.

But what I need is a function just like rowCount() that will give me the FOUND rows not the AFFECTED rows or something that will let me force the update on the MySQL table.

I have looked and googled the thing but I can't find anything and I am worried that it might be because it doesn't exist.

I have heard of something called `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` but I am not sure it is a PDO flag or how to use it (and I cant find anything on it).

What I was hoping to achieve with this is something like a REPLACE statement or an UPSERT without the need of a primary key.

If UPDATE return 0 rows then INSERT the row in the table.

***EDIT***

Sorry for the mistake I forgot the WHERE clause in the query. As pointed out in the comments.

**EDIT**

I am still doing research on google for this and found a MySQL function called `FOUND_ROWS()` but It seems it need to be use in a separate query which doesn't really help since I could just do a SELECT beforehand. But this might give you guys an idea that I haven't think of yet.

Thank you for all the help guys (and girls).

Comment: You really should be using placeholders when composing queries with PDO to avoid nasty SQL injection bugs. All this takes is adding some data to your `execute` call, and even makes the query itself far more readable.

Comment: You will update a lot of rows with this `UPDATE` query. Every single row will be updated (not counting the one existing with this data). Don't you think adding a `WHERE` clause would be better?

Comment: @tadman I already knew how to add parameters to PDO statement, in fact I am doing it in the actual code but I dumb down the code for the question.

Comment: @VMai Sorry I corrected the query :S

Comment: @Sebastien Alright. Just wanted to be sure, since the next sorts of questions if you omit that are due to escaping bugs.

Comment: Is EmplCode `UNIQUE`? If yes, then you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @VMai No EmplCode is not UNIQUE unfortunately it would have been easier if so but I am not the guy who created the table and I cant change it...

Comment: i understand. i deleted my comment as you already answered it with your comment to VMal.

Comment: @RyanVincent If there is no other way to do I will probably have to do a SELECT first and then do an INSERT or an UPDATE depending on the results of SELECT but if I can save it with something like rowCount or just by adding something to the query itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L613) is a mysql connection option. 
It works only as PDO connection option as well, like

```
$PDOObject = new PDO($dsn,DB_USER,DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => TRUE));
```

after this, `rowCount` returns the number of found rows, not affected.

```
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: @Sebastien I have some cases where this option worked! If you look at link i've posted on my answer you can see it is an option of mysql_driver. Look `Ome Ko` topic on [php site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930)